# Indicating the axes

Tags: plotting, formatting

I want to scale the $x$ axis of the plot by $x^0$ and the $y$ axis by $\tan x$. Is this possible ?

```
 Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

EDIT:
Actually  wanted to know that how to include the axes name like in the below picture mentioned by (x and y) and the curve whiched is defiend in the picture by $f(x)=x^2$?
[image]

Comment: Try looking at the help file for `PlotRange`.

Comment: I think you cannot because Axes units must be numbers.

Comment: I must say I do not understand what do you want, could you please explain it? What's x^0?

Comment: I don't understand what output you want, can you clarify a bit? (One interpretation I came up with is that you want to label the axes, in which case: `Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
 AxesLabel -> {Defer[x^0], Defer[Tan[x]]}]` if this is not what you want can you perhaps find a picture of how you want it to look )

Comment: How is your edit related to the first sentence?

Comment: Your edit seems to ask a completely different question. The first question was interesting. This new question can be solved with a quick look at the documentation for styling plots and drawing graphics. AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AxesStyle -> 
 Arrowheads[0.05], Epilog -> 
  Text[TraditionalForm[f[x] == x^2], {7, 6.25}]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
Plot[ArcTan@Tan[x], {x, 0, 10},
  Ticks -> {
    Table[{i, i*180 °/π}, {i, 0, 10, π/6}],
    Table[{i, N@Tan[i]}, {i, -90 °, 90 °, 10 °}]
  }
]
```

The resulting plot has an $x$-axis marked of in degrees (my interpretation of `x^0`) and the $y$-axis is scaled according to `ArcTan`, much like `LogPlot` is scaled according to `Exp`.

[image: ArcTanPlot of Tan(x)]

Comment: Ahhh, `0` was `\[deg]` :) I think it is good interpretation :)

Comment: I have edited the question.